# Script to get a list of all images that are detached?

Tags: plugin-development

In my functions.php, I have a need to list all images in the uploads folder which are not currently attached to a post in the WP database.

It appears that every time an image is uploaded to the WP uploads folder (via FTP or via Media Manager), a records gets inserted in the WP database, right?

How can I obtain a list of all images that are not currently attached to any post?

Comment: Just curious, is this somehow related to your other question? If so, I think there is some plugin that inserts all non-associated files in wp-uploads to the library as un-attached / detached entries into the database.

Comment: Hakre, are you referring to.. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-from-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => 0
); 
$attachments = get_posts($args);

if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        the_attachment_link($post->ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: @sorich: Thanks very much. This definitely gets me much closer. Its returning a bit more data than I need though. For example, it appears that the image itself is contained in ["guid"]=&gt; string(59) "http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/theImage.png" so that's the part I'm looking for. Any way to call get_posts and just return the "guid" value?

Comment: I would not recommend using the guid as it was not meant to be used as link. The guid format may change in the future (http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/6492). You should use `the_attachment_link($post->ID, false)`, e.g., to get the link to the image.

Comment: In WP 3.1, you will be able to get only one field with get_posts: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14777. In the meanwhile, you can use the filter `posts_fields`.

Comment: Not true, the patch does not specify that only one field can be returned, it's extending get_posts to allow selection of given fields, rather than simply returning all, this brings get_posts inline with other functions that support the same (one example would be get_terms).

Comment: @t31os: based on your explanation, I don't see how what I said is not true.  I did not say that only one field will always be returned. What is the difference between "only one field can be returned" and "allow selection of given fields" (if I can select only one field e.g.)? Am I missing something?

Comment: @sorich - You said: "you will be able to get only one field with get_posts" ... you can get a number of fields if you want, there's no restriction.. (maybe you just worded the comment poorly?)

Comment: @sorich: How can I integrate the_attachment_link($post->ID, false) into your answer code? I'm just using ['guid'] because that's how the attachment image link is returned when doing get_posts().

Comment: @t31os: Sorry, I did not know that 'be able to' could be interpreted as 'always'. I am not a native english speaker. :)

Comment: @Scott B: I edited my answer.

Comment: @sorich - Like i said, i think it's just how you worded your reply, no problem mate, no harm done... ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you need that in your UI to manage those:

`/wp-admin/upload.php?detached=1`

Add the address to your blog in front.

Or more descriptive:

Log into your admin then use the menu: *Media* -> *Library*. Select the *Unattached* link above the lists' filter drop-down.